# Why did my top-bar reputation not match my profile after a post I downvoted was deleted?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, reputation

Curious thing, I downvoted an answer and my rep dropped by 3 points, the answer was deleted and you can see my rep went up by 3 points, and it was showing the +1 green rep notification (missed the screen shot).There was no other activity on my account, this all happened within a short time (approx 30 mins).

[image]

As you can see there's nothing else, as the downvote rep was reversed.

[image]

Comment: I would think a question you suggested an edit on was removed, and you can't see that because 10k stuff. And the one rep, well, dammit it seems something's not working properly.

Comment: @TIPS I don't suggest edits on SO I have over 10k rep.

Comment: Yvette but didn't you suggest any edits before 2k? (BTW it's just an assumption and might be incorrect, and who are we kidding, I saw your SO rep as 1759).

Comment: @TIPS it's been a loooooooooong time since I made a suggested edit  LOL and it wouldn't explain it disappearing and then reappearing. As for the 1759, glasses or a bigger screen might help?

Comment: Though you could still suggest edits, but for tag wikis and excerpts, until you hit 20k.

Comment: @nicael yes!! very good point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You downvoted three answers and lost three points; those posts were then deleted, and you gained the points back. These aren't shown in the "achievements" dropdown since that'd involve linking to deleted posts; they *should* show up in your profile's reputation history, but only if you check the "show removed posts" checkbox (actually not 100% certain about that; they *should*, but there are some subtleties there that I don't always remember and this might be one of them - test it).

The discrepancy between your profile reputation and top-bar reputation comes from the need for the system to recalculate your reputation after the posts are removed; this usually takes a few minutes (which is nice, since it makes it slightly harder for someone to be certain who downvoted them by watching their reputation while deleting their own posts). As of about 17 minutes ago (7 minutes before you posted this question, 3 minutes after the last question was deleted), they should have been identical.

Comment: ah yes! the other two answers were deleted minutes after the downvotes. Sorry this question was a bit lame. Where's the showed removed posts?

Comment: I don't think the show removed posts thing is a happening thing Shog

Comment: ok. Well, that's annoying, but probably still by-design.

Comment: It should still exist, @Yvette: http://i.stack.imgur.com/OT4MD.png.

Comment: @hichris123 ah yes it does! thank you